GDAL's JPEGXL Driver shows bad behaviours for lossy compression of multispectral images
test.tif is a 31x512x482 image, and lossless compression with the following command is as expected.
gdal_translate -of JPEGXL -co EFFORT=7 -co DISTANCE=0 test.tif test.jxl
But lossy compression with the following command using different values of d is as unexpected.
gdal_translate -of JPEGXL -co EFFORT=7 -co DISTANCE=d test.tif test.jxl
I increase the d value (even up to 25), but there is still a big bitstream, i.e., no too much bit reduction but with reconstructed PSNR decreases.

Could you share some test data? I removed the jpeg-2000 tag, jpegxl is a different thing.

I added these tags because I am new user and cannot add new tag "jpegxl". I used the ARAR 1K data https://github.com/boazarad/ARAD_1K. I think any multispectral images with more than 4 bands can produce my issue.

Don't you get this warning "Warning 6: '0' is an unexpected value for DISTANCE creation option that should be >= 0.1."? The right creation option is -co lossless=yes. But YES is the default and invalid distance gets skipped so the result is the same.

From https://www.reddit.com/r/jpegxl/comments/xd4q4w/using_jpegxl_for_multichannel_satellite_images/  "we haven't really been optimizing for images with more than just alpha (i.e. a single extra channel)" but that was 2 years ago. I do not know what libjxl version GDAL is using.

There was a bug in the GDAL JPEGXL driver. All channels after the R, G, and B channels were always written uncompressed. The issue is fixed by https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/11099

Yes, thank you for the information.
